# Change Custom Colors in MS Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, graph, ms-office

I m trying to change the color theme in access and for all the charts (bar,pie,margins,area etc) i want to add new color scheme .
I m using Ms Access 2000 ,i figured a way to change each color manually by clicking on the graph and then tools-->options -->Color-->chart fills but2 problems with this approach:

1.Limits the number of colors to 8
2.I need to manually change for each graph i have over 100 graphs

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once edited the colors of columns in charts programmatically. I am not sure anymore for which version of access though. It doesnt work anymore in access2003, so it's probably working in access 2000.

Lets say your chart is called "OLEObject".

You can edit the background like this:

```
    Me.OLEObject.Object.ActiveChart.PlotArea.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientHorizontal, Variant:=2, Degree:=0.8
```

to edit the color, text etc of your columns/pie you can access the seriescollection.

```
   With Me.OLEObject.Object.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i)
       .Name = "name"
       .Values = "={" & 10 & "}"
       .Interior.color = 2
       .ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True

       With .DataLabels

           .Font.Size = 10 
           .Orientation = xlUpward
       End With

       With .Fill
            .OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientHorizontal, Variant:=1, Degree:=0.4
            .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
       End With

   End With
```

You can add/delete columns programmatically too:

```
      .SeriesCollection(3).delete

      .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
```

Comment: Finally I could get it to work using this code GraphA.SeriesCollection(I).Interior.Color = RGB(50,100,100) But now it doesnt show the exact color it showing some other color than intended color ,Any ideas?

Comment: I dont know how to set an RGB color. I remember having trouble with this as well, so I simply used the internal color scheme. Have a look at this [link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm). It's the color palette for excel 2000, I assume access 2000 is using the same. It is limited to 56 colors though. If this palette will do, you can set the color as I did by specifying the index.

Comment: I just had a look at my code again and found out I was using this code: Interior.color = eval(RGB(50, 100, 100))

Comment: I am just curious, but did you find a solution a yet?

Comment: Nope,I just manually changed the colors under tools-->Options-->colors

Comment: hmm, ok. the only other thing I could think of is, if you are fine with the 56 colors I mentioned earlier, that you set the property Interior.ColorIndex