# Change chart colors in a form

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use VBA to change the colors palette of a "pie chart" in a report of ms-access 2010. I am printing it in a report & My chart is the result of a query than I created with the help of the "chart wizard" (because I am using the spanish edition of MS-office I don't know the real name of the utility).

So far I've tried:

```
Private Sub Gráfico0_Updated(Code As Integer)
    Gráfico0.Recolor (RGB(0, 0, 256))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Just found this link, may be too old for your version but can't hurt to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476626/change-custom-colors-in-ms-access-using-vba

Comment: Here's another http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/vba-to-control-colors-in-access-chart-4696019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution without codding and it's pretty easy. From the "design view" (this is very important because the menu is different in the other views) select edit and then you will open a window were you can customize the chart with several option like showing the percentage and overriding the default colors.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and change the color number as needed

```
ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 344
```

Comment: Tried that code inside Enter, GotFocus & Exit Subs but I can't make it work.

Comment: Did you try it with Gráfico0 instead of ActiveChart?